# Value Error. Cannot assign query set. It must be an instance

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, valueerror

I want to create object in my comment model.
It's my Reply model to a post.

```
class Reply(MPTTModel):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    detail = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

It's my view function for reply.

```
def post_detail(request,id,**kwargs):
    post = Post.objects.all().filter(id=id)
    comment = CommentReply.objects.filter(post=id)
    context = {'post': post, 'comment': comment}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comments = request.POST.get('comment')
        Reply.objects.create(
                post=post, detail=comments, author = request.user)
    else:
        return render(request, 'khalidblog_app/full_detail.html', context)

    return render(request,'khalidblog_app/full_detail.html',context)
```

I'm using for loop in my template:

```
{% for post in post %}
    <img alt='' src='{{ post.image.url }}' class='avatar avatar-80 photo' height='80' width='80' />
    <div class="eltd-author-description-text-holder">
        <h5 class="eltd-author-name"> {{post.author}} </h5>
    <div class="eltd-author-text">
        <p>{{post.title}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="eltd-author-text">
        <p>{{post.content}}</p>
        <hr>
    </div>
{%endfor%}
```

When I run this view function It shows a value error as follows.

```
Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Post: Author : zorainTiTleFirst PostDated :2021-01-17 16:27:47.043869+00:00>]>": "Reply.post" must be a "Post" instance.
```

How I can set the forignkey(Post) in this reply model using this view function?

Comment: change this line: post = Post.objects.all().filter(id=id) to post = Post.objects.filter(id=id).first()    It will return first obect in the filter. If you use get like this: post = Post.objects.get(id=id),  it would raise exception if the object doesn't exist. You can also do: post = Post.objects.filter(id=id)[0]

Answer (score 1):

Your 'post' variable is pointing to a QuerySet of Post objects, rather than a single instance. You should use get() instead of filter() as follows:

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
```

**Update**: You shared in the comments that you were using a for loop in your template. A for loop is designed for iterating over a group of objects (e.g. a QuerySet that would be returned by using a filter()). If you just want to render the values of fields for a single instance, you do not need to use a for loop.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter) is a link to the Django docs, for filter() - which returns a QuerySet (group of objects).

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get) is a link to the Django docs, for get() - which returns single object.

Comment: This isn't related to your question, however, there is no need for your else: statement in the view. The return call in this else statement is a repetition of the below return call, which would get executed anyway.

Comment: when I tried .get then it says post object is not iterable. So it means I have yo use another variable for object create. as follows... post1 =Post.objects.get(id=id) Reply.objects.create( post=post1, detail=comments, author = request.user)

Comment: It sounds like this second error you are referring to might be related to code in your HTML template. Please could you share this as well? Perhaps you are using a forloop such as for something in post, which would not make sense.

Comment: Yes I'm using for loop.                                                                                                                   {% for post in post %}
<img alt='' src="{{ post.image.url }}"
     class='avatar avatar-80 photo' height='80' width='80' />
     <div class="eltd-author-description-text-holder">
<h5 class="eltd-author-name">
{{post.author}} </h5>
        <div class="eltd-author-text">
<p>{{post.title}}</p></div>
<div class="eltd-author-text">
<p>{{post.content}}</p>
    <hr>


</div>
{%endfor%}

Comment: If I don't use for then It don't show the post.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the template code. You can remove the {% for ... %} and {% endfor... %} tags completely. You don't need them, as you are not looping over a group of posts, you just want to display the values of certain fields on a particular instance.

Comment: When I remove the loop e.g.  <h5 class="eltd-author-name">
{{post.id}} </h5> It don't work.

Comment: Have you tried removing the for loop, since changing the line in my original answer? You will need to do both.

Comment: Yes Sir, I got it. Thanks a lot. It's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

On the very first line of your function, you are using .filter() method which returns QuerySet (List of Objects in short), where you should have ideally used .get() method.
.get() returns a single object which the assignment on line 6 actually expects.

Comment: when I tried .get then it says post object is not iterable. So it means I have yo use another variable for object create. as follows...                                                                                           post1 =Post.objects.get(id=id)                                                                                                       Reply.objects.create(
                post=post1, detail=comments, author = request.user)

Answer (score 0):

since your 'post' variable is pointing to a QuerySet of Post objects you can directly select the first element in the QuerySet as like this :

```
 Reply.objects.create(
                post=post[0], detail=comments, author = request.user)
```

Comment: this solution already mentioned in the comments

Comment: Yes Sir I got it.